# transfer textfile contents into database python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm a little new to python/sqlite. I'm trying to transfer the contents of a textile into a database. The textile is formatted like this:

```
hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello
```

I parse the textile into a 2d list with each line as its own tuple i.e. [hello, hello, hello]. I would like to transfer this list into a database where each element is an attribute and each tuple is its own row - with a few blank attributes since each line is of different length.

I keep the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied
```

I'm not sure why this is. I thought I addressed this with my query_string variable. If anyone could help me, that would be great. My code is below:

```
import sqlite3

ins = open( "foo.txt", "r" ) 
parseTable = []

for line in ins:
   row = line.rstrip().split(',') 
   parseTable.append(row)

#print parseTable

conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE sample (Item_0 TEXT, Item_1 TEXT, Item_2 TEXT, Item_3 TEXT, Item_4 TEXT)''')

query_string = 'INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

c.executemany(query_string, parseTable)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please don't just insert the solution into your question; it didn't clarify the problem and makes my answer look incorrect to boot.

Comment: And I understood your question; that's what my answer below *does*.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I didn't intend that to be a solution. Sorry I screwed it up.

Comment: You also have a mistake in generating `var_string` variable, but luckily you don't actually *use* that string. You want to use `len(parseTable[0])` there, the length of a row, not the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in some extra `None` values to pad the rows:

```
for line in ins:
    row = line.split()[:5]
    row.extend([None] * (5 - len(row)))
    parseTable.append(row)
```

This splits your sample data on *spaces* (not commas), caps rows to at most 5 elements, then adds `None` values if the length is *below* 4 elements.

The `None` values are translated into `NULL`s for the missing columns for those rows.

Demo:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> ins = '''\
... hello hello hello
... hello hello hello hello hello
... hello hello hello hello
... '''.splitlines()
>>> parseTable = []
>>> for line in ins:
...     row = line.split()[:5]
...     row.extend([None] * (5 - len(row)))
...     parseTable.append(row)
... 
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('''CREATE TABLE sample (Item_0 TEXT, Item_1 TEXT, Item_2 TEXT, Item_3 TEXT, Item_4 TEXT)''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d8960>
>>> query_string = 'INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
>>> c.executemany(query_string, parseTable)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d8960>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> c.execute('SELECT * FROM sample')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d8960>
>>> for row in c:
...     print row
... 
(u'hello', u'hello', u'hello', None, None)
(u'hello', u'hello', u'hello', u'hello', u'hello')
(u'hello', u'hello', u'hello', u'hello', None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the change but now every line is a single attribute. I want to make each individual element a different attribute. So how do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow you; each row contains the values from your file's lines, plus enough `None` values to pad each row to 5 values. The term 'attribute' usually refers to something different in Python, those are values on objects instead (`someobject.attribute`).

Comment: Ok let me make an edit above. I mean 'attribute' as in an individual field in any database.

Comment: @dave: those are generally called 'columns'

Comment: Ok, Sorry about my bad communication. What I mean is every line is one single column now. I'd like multiple columns.

Comment: @dave: ah, but that's because your file has **spaces** not commas. :-)